# tabulator adding "numrow" once data were pulled

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I've a table of **unknown data** (*some columns and rows* ) ,I'm at the point where i require to use the function `table.updateData()` which requires column `id` to be existing within the data construction which i can't guarantee as the data are pulled from an **unknown source** .

is there's a way around this or is there's any **alternative** way of updating the data later ?

- *p.s. i only use vanilla **javascript** not **jquery***

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a unique index set on each row of the data in order for Tabulator to know which row you want to refer to.

You can set this to any column field in the row data using the ***index*** option in the table constructor

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    index:"age", //set the index field to the "age" field.
});
```

By default this is set to the ***id*** filed

If you want to set this locally you can use a mutator to create a value in this field for you:

```
//define variable to count index's to ensure they are unique
var index = 0;

//define custom mutator
var idMutator = function(value, data, type, params, component){
    //value - original value of the cell
    //data - the data for the row
    //type - the type of mutation occurring  (data|edit)
    //params - the mutatorParams object from the column definition
    //component - when the "type" argument is "edit", this contains the cell component for the edited cell, otherwise it is the column component for the column

    return index++; //return the index for the row.
}

//column definition
{field:"id", mutator:idMutator, visible:false}
```

However if you are updating the data from a remote source then there is no wat to tie that back to the data in your table.

It is standard practice to include an index or unique identifier  in the data of this sort to allow syncing between client and server side

Comment: is it possible to use Mutator to add a `numrow` column myself right after the client add the data ? anything that identify the rows from my side would be much better than to expect it from my clients.

Comment: ues that is esentially what the example above does, just replace the "id" field value in the column definition with "rownum" and set the "index" option to "rownum" in the table constructor. that wont help you though if you are going to update data that they have already sent over unless you have a way to link it back to that original data

Comment: basically i just want to add column right away after someone insert the data and use it as a numrow instead of anything the client represents , is that possible ?

Comment: yes, using the mutator code i have outlined in my answer it does exactly that. if you dont want it to be hidden, simply dont include the visible:false code that is in the column definition obejct in the example